# Decode HTML escaped characters back to normal string in C#

Tags: c#, html, escaping

My question is simple. I searched a little online, but could not find a quick way to unescape HTML text in a string.

For example:
`"&lt; &gt; &amp;"` should be returned to "< > &" as a string.

Is there a quick way, or do I have to write my own unescaper?

Comment: Did you tried _anything_? Show your effort..

Comment: @SonerGönül Soner, figured I'd let you know since I see you commenting a lot. It's said: did you **try** anything :D

Comment: @SonerGönül no, I did not, that's why I'm asking. Should I write my own unescaper or does such a thing exist?

Comment: You did not do any searching. My google search comes up with tons of results on the subject.

Comment: @MarioStoilov Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) Especially the `Do your homework` section.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

use `System.Web.HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` or `System.Net.WebUtility.HtmlDecode`

```
var decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode("&lt; &gt; &amp;");
```

Comment: Is there a difference between these two?

Comment: it does not unescape &#0000106&#0000097&#0000118

Comment: @jazzcat, did you find the solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using .NET 4.5 then you can use the `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode` method.

Comment: HttpUtility.HtmlDecode is available since .NET 1.1.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.htmldecode.aspx

Answer (score 1):

```
HttpUtility.UrlDecode("Your escaped String", System.Text.Encoding.Default);
```